# A way to parse tmTheme files for getting settings?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

I'm pretty new to coding in general, and am trying to create an editor plugin which uses sublime files like sublime-syntax and tmThemes for things like syntax highlighting. However I need to find a way to parse XML by key value so that i can simply search through tmTheme files like settings.backgroundcolor etc... in js.

How would I be able to do this in JS?

Comment: Can you post an example of a file and what you want to extract from it?

Answer (score 2):

As tmTheme format is indeed [just plain XML](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/color_schemes_tmtheme.html), you would want to find yourself a XML parser (there is more than enough of these) and pick it apart - the format is pretty straightforward, the only subject of consideration would be `<dict>` (for which you would have to loop over it's children to recognize subsequent `<key>`+`<value>` pairs.